# /admin/actions/users/login 404

Tags: users, control-panel, login

When trying to login to my live env on craft, I get the following error in the javascript console.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) (login, line 0)
```

This only happens in the live environment, which is weird because the DB and front-end code are synced between local and live. There is also a staging website where the login page works.

Comment: Recently i faced the same issue, and it was due to ssl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I looked into this a bunch more tonight to satisfy my curiosity, and here's what is happening.

The default rewrite rule that Forge is apparently adding is this:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/?(.*)") {
    return 301 "$1$2";
}
```

What this does is essentially it just removes `index.php` from URLs, which seems harmless enough.

On the login screen, Craft has a JavaScript that does an XHR to the following URL:

`/index.php/admin/actions/users/login`

This matches the rule above, and gets rewritten as:

`/admin/actions/users/login`

The problem here is that [redirects will never resend POST data](https://serverfault.com/questions/312111/how-do-i-get-nginx-to-forward-http-post-requests-via-rewrite) and the request now becomes a `GET`.

Well, sure enough, the UsersController gets hit, and the `actionLogin()` method is called, but:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn())
    {
        // Too easy.
        $this->_handleSuccessfulLogin(false);
    }

    if (craft()->request->isPostRequest())
    {
```

[image]

...because the request is no longer a POST request, Craft bails, and request 404s, and everyone is unhappy.

So, how to fix it? Probably Forge should check for `$request_method != POST` before attempting the 301 redirect.

**Solution:** If you're using Craft, just remove the above rule, it isn't needed.

Answer (score 6):

What server provisioner are you using? Forge? Something else? If it's Forge, it's most likely this:

https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/895726366477344772

Also here are some Nginx configs (with Forge examples) that are known to work with Craft CMS 2.x and 3.x: [Nginx-Craft](https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I am using forge... weird that this happens in one environment but not another. I owe you a beer!

Comment: Is this a new development? Like in that last couple days? That config does not appear in older provisions.

Comment: Yeah it must be fairly recent, because I I've created sites with Forge pretty recently, and this default config wasn't there.