# What might cause logins to work locally yet not in deployed environment?

Tags: admin, login, mysql

We're getting a 404 (or a Craft 'page not found' error) with this path on the remote server:

`http://foo.example.net/admin/actions/users/login`

Same database using remote mySQL. Local logins work fine.

Craft CMS 2.6.2989

Answer (score 1):

Crikey...

[/admin/actions/users/login 404](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21602/admin-actions-users-login-404)

https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/895726366477344772

Forge!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a fun one I ran into. The server configs here are known to work with Nginx & Craft CMS 2.x & 3.x: [Nginx-Craft](https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft)